# Why can't remove the event listener on sibling's?

Tags: javascript, html, event-listener

```js
function show1() {
  console.log("ok1");
  document.getElementById("a2").removeEventListener("click", delegate);
}

function show2() {
  console.log("ok2");
}

function show3() {
  console.log("ok3");
}

function delegate(event) {
  var flag = event.target;
  switch (flag.id) {
    case "a1":
      show1();
      break;
    case "a2":
      show2();
      break;
    case "a3":
      show3();
      break;
  }
}

ob = document.getElementById("tl");
ob.addEventListener("click", delegate);
```

```html
<ul id="tl">
  <li id="a1">a1</li>
  <li id="a2">a2</li>
  <li id="a3">a3</li>
</ul>
```

The parent node `ul` contains three son nodes `li`,bind a event listener on the parent node ,let `ul` delegate all node's event listening.
My expectation:
when you click `a1`, `show1` function will remove  event listener on its sibling whose id is `a2`.
That is to say,you click `li` whose id is `a2` after clicking `li` whose id is `a1` ,`ok2` will not show on console.

The real action:
You click `li` whose id is `a2` after clicking `li` whose id is `a1` ,`ok2` will show on console.

Why

`document.getElementById("a2").removeEventListener("click",delegate);`

can't remove the event listener on sibling's?
How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a listener is attached to an element, the only thing you can do about removing it is to remove the same listener from the same element - you can't remove it from a child element because it's not attached to the child element.

For the functionality you're looking for, you might add the node you want to "remove" the click functionality from to a `Set`, and in the parent node's handler, check that the `event.target` (the `flag` variable) is not included in that `Set`:

```js
const elementsToIgnore = new Set();
function show1() {
  console.log("ok1");
  elementsToIgnore.add(document.getElementById("a2"));
}

function show2() {
  console.log("ok2");
}

function show3() {
  console.log("ok3");
}

function delegate(event) {
  var flag = event.target;
  if (elementsToIgnore.has(flag)) return;
  switch (flag.id) {
    case "a1":
      show1();
      break;
    case "a2":
      show2();
      break;
    case "a3":
      show3();
      break;
  }
}

ob = document.getElementById("tl");
ob.addEventListener("click", delegate);
```

```html
<ul id="tl">
  <li id="a1">a1</li>
  <li id="a2">a2</li>
  <li id="a3">a3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is beacus you are adding event listener to `ul` not `li`. Add `event` handler to `li` as following

```js
function show1(){
    console.log("ok1");
    document.getElementById("a2").removeEventListener("click",delegate);
}

function show2(){
    console.log("ok2");
}

function show3(){
    console.log("ok3");
}

function delegate(event)
{
    var flag = event.target;
    switch(flag.id){
        case "a1":
            show1();
            break;
        case "a2":
            show2();     
            break;
        case "a3":
            show3();
            break;
    }
}

ob = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for(let i=0; i<ob.length; i++){
ob[i].addEventListener("click",delegate);
}
```

```html
<ul id="tl">
 <li id="a1">a1</li>
 <li id="a2">a2</li>
 <li id="a3">a3</li>
</ul>
```